# .lib-popup-button-close-icon is undefined

Tags: magento2

> frontend/Magento/kiegeszitoshop/en_US/css/styles-m.less
>   .lib-popup-button-close-icon is undefined in
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2sample/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Magento/kiegeszitoshop/en_US/css/sourc
>   /_popups.less>

I m getting this error when i m deploying static content using composer..

Have anyone any idea what is going wrong here??

Comment: same here :(
no idea what is going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the luma theme has an error in the code, in which hasnt been fixed.

goto line 30 of **`_popups.less`**

```
.lib-popup-button-close-icon
```

should be

```
._lib-popup-button-close-icon
```

then on line 23 of the same file I just removed all those less functions.

...seems to work

Comment: magento 2 is a joke btw--happy coding! The github repo is littered with bugs tread carefully my friend--god speed.

Comment: Yes you are right ! I thing people have stop using magento2 for at least 1year. And I will check your answer and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is a bug.
If your theme inherit from Theme_Luma edit file:

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source/_popups.less
```

Or if your theme inherit from Theme_blank edit this file:

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_popups.less
```

On end of file copy this content:

```
    //  Popup close button use icon
.lib-popup-button-close-icon(
    @_popup-button-close-icon,
    @_popup-icon-font-content,
    @_popup-icon-font,
    @_popup-icon-font-size,
    @_popup-icon-font-line-height,
    @_popup-icon-font-color,
    @_popup-icon-font-color-hover,
    @_popup-icon-font-color-active,
    @_popup-icon-font-margin,
    @_popup-icon-font-vertical-align,
    @_popup-icon-font-position,
    @_popup-icon-font-text-hide
) when (@_popup-button-close-icon = true) {
    .lib-button-icon(
        @_icon-font-content: @_popup-icon-font-content,
        @_icon-font: @_popup-icon-font,
        @_icon-font-size: @_popup-icon-font-size,
        @_icon-font-line-height: @_popup-icon-font-line-height,
        @_icon-font-color: @_popup-icon-font-color,
        @_icon-font-color-hover: @_popup-icon-font-color-hover,
        @_icon-font-color-active: @_popup-icon-font-color-active,
        @_icon-font-margin: @_popup-icon-font-margin,
        @_icon-font-vertical-align: @_popup-icon-font-vertical-align,
        @_icon-font-position: @_popup-icon-font-position,
        @_icon-font-text-hide: @_popup-icon-font-text-hide
    );
}

//  Popup close button reset
._lib-popup-button-close-reset (
    @_popup-button-close-reset
) when (@_popup-button-close-reset = true) {
    .lib-button-reset();
}
```

Above code is from vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/lib/_popups.less

Finally clean static folder and run command

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/; rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried Chris's solution which is to change

```
.lib-popup-button-close-icon
```

to

```
._lib-popup-button-close-icon
```

on line 30 of _popups.less and then on line 23 of the same file I just removed all those less functions.  But I kept on having the same problems.  Even after clearing all the necessary cache, static, and var folders.

I then tried Marcin's solution and that seems to have fixed the problems for me.  The only caveat is that I had to add this code to all the themes and child themes that had a bug in _popups.less.  Otherwise the deploy static view files command would throw an error and halt.

```
//  Popup close button use icon
.lib-popup-button-close-icon(
    @_popup-button-close-icon,
    @_popup-icon-font-content,
    @_popup-icon-font,
    @_popup-icon-font-size,
    @_popup-icon-font-line-height,
    @_popup-icon-font-color,
    @_popup-icon-font-color-hover,
    @_popup-icon-font-color-active,
    @_popup-icon-font-margin,
    @_popup-icon-font-vertical-align,
    @_popup-icon-font-position,
    @_popup-icon-font-text-hide
) when (@_popup-button-close-icon = true) {
    .lib-button-icon(
        @_icon-font-content: @_popup-icon-font-content,
        @_icon-font: @_popup-icon-font,
        @_icon-font-size: @_popup-icon-font-size,
        @_icon-font-line-height: @_popup-icon-font-line-height,
        @_icon-font-color: @_popup-icon-font-color,
        @_icon-font-color-hover: @_popup-icon-font-color-hover,
        @_icon-font-color-active: @_popup-icon-font-color-active,
        @_icon-font-margin: @_popup-icon-font-margin,
        @_icon-font-vertical-align: @_popup-icon-font-vertical-align,
        @_icon-font-position: @_popup-icon-font-position,
        @_icon-font-text-hide: @_popup-icon-font-text-hide
    );
}

//  Popup close button reset
._lib-popup-button-close-reset (
    @_popup-button-close-reset
) when (@_popup-button-close-reset = true) {
    .lib-button-reset();
}
```